# Метод DELETE заменяется методом OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, rest, delete

```
function Delete() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3002/pulpits/1`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
}
```

отправляю на сервер DELETE запрос на локальный сервер, но приходит OPTIONS(раньше этот же код работал)

Comment: Это поди [кроссдоменный сложный запрос](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). [Здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#neprostye-zaprosy) информации может быть больше. Вероятно, суть в том, что клиент сначала отправляет OPTIONS, чтобы понять, что все хорошо, а потом выполняет основной запрос. Но тут что-то случилось, наверное, просто в вопросе не все предоставили. Клиент на том же порту, что и сервер?

Comment: да, к тому же порту

Answer (score 0):

Решено, нужно сначала обработать запрос OPTIONS:

```
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
res.end();
```